# balancing two input number fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to balance two input number fields using jquery based on the max value set for both. for example its like a balance, if one side goes down the other goes up and vice versa. another example if the max value is 20 then if i enter 5 in input field one then 15 would be left in input field two.
Need the help Thanks. Haven't started coding it as yet stuck trying to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried anything, the logic seems fairly straight forward -> `value2 = 20 - value1` etc.

Comment: yes i tried but gave up. i dont know how to code the function using jquery. its not balancing the two fields i have the class set like input field one and input feild two but in the function its not catching them based on the class i place.

Comment: If you want help with your code, you should show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to attach the input eventhandler on all of the relevant input fields. This event handler will compare the current input value of a input fields to the total/max value variable and find the remainder accordingly. The event handler then finds the other input fields and assigns them with the appropriate remainder values.

> **Note**: This allows you to add as many inputs as you want and it will
>   balance them all out. Just remember to add the `balance` class on the
>   input field.

```js
var total = 20;
$('.balance').on('input', function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    this.value = value = 0;
  } else if (value > total) {
    this.value = value = total;
  }/* else if (value < 0) {
    this.value = value = 0;
  }
  * Remove this comment if value shouldn't be negative.
  */
  var remainder = total - value;
  var otherInputs = $('.balance');
  otherInputs.splice($.inArray(this,otherInputs),1);
  var remainderDiv = remainder/otherInputs.length;
  $.each(otherInputs, function(input) {
      otherInputs[input].value = remainderDiv;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="balance">
<input type="number" class="balance">
```

**Update**: The two inputs can be less than the max but never higher.

```js
var max = 20;
$('.balance').on('input', function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    value = 0;
  }
  var otherInputs = $('.balance');
  var sum = 0;
  $.each(otherInputs, function(input) {
      sum += parseInt(otherInputs[input].value);
  });
  if (sum > max)
    this.value = max - (sum - value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="balance">
<input type="number" class="balance">
```

Comment: how could i pass a counter variable in javascript append

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by that.

Comment: ok dont worry i got it done. now i was wondering how can i add a counter to a class name in jquery like $('.balance'+i).attr{}.. if thats correct OR $('.balance'+i+'').attr{}.

Comment: ok how would you do it that the remainder doesnt go in the input field two. but it should still minus from each other though when the user puts in a value. so if max =10. when the user inputs 5 in field one and puts zero in field two that would be correct. But if he puts 5 in field one and 6 in field two that would be incorrect. how could i do that using your code.

Comment: @Lee Added an update which does not allow the inputs to be higher than the max defined var.

Comment: ok having another problem i am using it on a select dropdown the first code works when i select an option it changes the value but with the updated code it stills remain on the previous option.

Answer (score 1):

here's a fiddle to get you started (and maybe finished):

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/xwyrrw53/1/

html:

```
<input type='number' id='first' class='balancable'/>
<input type='number' id='second' class='balancable'/>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    var max = 20;
    var balanceOpposite = {
      'first': 'second',
      'second': 'first',
    }
    $('.balancable').on('input', function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var thisVal = $(this).val();
      $('#' + balanceOpposite[id]).val(20 - thisVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: ok how would you do it that the remainder doesnt go in the input field two. but it should still minus from each other though when the user puts in a value. so if max =10. when the user inputs 5 in field one and puts zero in field two that would be correct. But if he puts 5 in field one and 6 in field two that would be incorrect. how could i do that using your code.